# Create spinning circle loading animation

Tags: ios, swift, animation

I'm trying to create a spinning circle loader animation like in the following Android project (https://github.com/pedant/sweet-alert-dialog).

[image]

I don't need the entire popup dialog - just the spinning part. It changes colors and spins indefinitly (until I choose to dismiss it).

I'm kind of new to swift and I've never been the kind to do animations. Here's what I have so far (found code in similar project for iOS):

The layers setup:

```
    outlineLayer.position = CGPointMake(0,
        0);
    outlineLayer.path = outlineCircle
    outlineLayer.fillColor = UIColor.clearColor().CGColor;
    outlineLayer.strokeColor = UIColor(red: 150.0/255.0, green: 216.0/255.0, blue: 115.0/255.0, alpha: 1.0).CGColor;
    outlineLayer.lineCap = kCALineCapRound
    outlineLayer.lineWidth = 4;
    outlineLayer.opacity = 0.1
    self.layer.addSublayer(outlineLayer)

    circleLayer.position = CGPointMake(0,
        0);
    circleLayer.path = path
    circleLayer.fillColor = UIColor.clearColor().CGColor;
    circleLayer.strokeColor = UIColor(red: 150.0/255.0, green: 216.0/255.0, blue: 115.0/255.0, alpha: 1.0).CGColor;
    circleLayer.lineCap = kCALineCapRound
    circleLayer.lineWidth = 4;
    circleLayer.actions = [
        "strokeStart": NSNull(),
        "strokeEnd": NSNull(),
        "transform": NSNull()
    ]
    self.layer.addSublayer(circleLayer)
```

Animation:

```
let strokeStart = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "strokeStart")
    let strokeEnd = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "strokeEnd")
    let factor = 0.545
    let timing = CAMediaTimingFunction(controlPoints: 0.3, 0.6, 0.8, 1.2)

    strokeEnd.fromValue = 0.00
    strokeEnd.toValue = 0.93
    strokeEnd.duration = 10.0 * factor
    strokeEnd.timingFunction = timing
    strokeEnd.autoreverses = true

    strokeStart.fromValue = 0.0
    strokeStart.toValue = 0.68
    strokeStart.duration =  10.0 * factor
    strokeStart.beginTime =  CACurrentMediaTime() + 3.0 * factor
    strokeStart.fillMode = kCAFillModeBackwards
    strokeStart.timingFunction = timing
    strokeStart.repeatCount = HUGE

    circleLayer.strokeStart = 0.68
    circleLayer.strokeEnd = 0.93

    self.circleLayer.addAnimation(strokeEnd, forKey: "strokeEnd")
    self.circleLayer.addAnimation(strokeStart, forKey: "strokeStart")
```

but what I have is not nearly close and I have no idea where to go from here. What I'm doing is changing a value and running seeing how it affects but I feel like I'm lost here.

How can I achieve such animation like in the example?

Comment: there might be open source projects/components that can do what you need to do (without you needing to reinvent something that has been done before).  I see two projects on CocoaControls.com, such as [GMDCircleLoader](https://www.cocoacontrols.com/controls/gmdcircleloader) and [CircleProgressView](https://www.cocoacontrols.com/controls/circleprogressview).

Comment: you got the solution ?

Comment: @Niharika Yes. you can see the selected answer.

Answer (score 105, accepted):

I didn't closely analyze the exact parameters of the animation, but this looks good to me:

[image: spinner view]

```
import UIKit

@IBDesignable
class SpinnerView : UIView {

    override var layer: CAShapeLayer {
        get {
            return super.layer as! CAShapeLayer
        }
    }

    override class var layerClass: AnyClass {
        return CAShapeLayer.self
    }

    override func layoutSubviews() {
        super.layoutSubviews()
        layer.fillColor = nil
        layer.strokeColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
        layer.lineWidth = 3
        setPath()
    }

    override func didMoveToWindow() {
        animate()
    }

    private func setPath() {
        layer.path = UIBezierPath(ovalIn: bounds.insetBy(dx: layer.lineWidth / 2, dy: layer.lineWidth / 2)).cgPath
    }

    struct Pose {
        let secondsSincePriorPose: CFTimeInterval
        let start: CGFloat
        let length: CGFloat
        init(_ secondsSincePriorPose: CFTimeInterval, _ start: CGFloat, _ length: CGFloat) {
            self.secondsSincePriorPose = secondsSincePriorPose
            self.start = start
            self.length = length
        }
    }

    class var poses: [Pose] {
        get {
            return [
                Pose(0.0, 0.000, 0.7),
                Pose(0.6, 0.500, 0.5),
                Pose(0.6, 1.000, 0.3),
                Pose(0.6, 1.500, 0.1),
                Pose(0.2, 1.875, 0.1),
                Pose(0.2, 2.250, 0.3),
                Pose(0.2, 2.625, 0.5),
                Pose(0.2, 3.000, 0.7),
            ]
        }
    }

    func animate() {
        var time: CFTimeInterval = 0
        var times = [CFTimeInterval]()
        var start: CGFloat = 0
        var rotations = [CGFloat]()
        var strokeEnds = [CGFloat]()

        let poses = type(of: self).poses
        let totalSeconds = poses.reduce(0) { $0 + $1.secondsSincePriorPose }

        for pose in poses {
            time += pose.secondsSincePriorPose
            times.append(time / totalSeconds)
            start = pose.start
            rotations.append(start * 2 * .pi)
            strokeEnds.append(pose.length)
        }

        times.append(times.last!)
        rotations.append(rotations[0])
        strokeEnds.append(strokeEnds[0])

        animateKeyPath(keyPath: "strokeEnd", duration: totalSeconds, times: times, values: strokeEnds)
        animateKeyPath(keyPath: "transform.rotation", duration: totalSeconds, times: times, values: rotations)

        animateStrokeHueWithDuration(duration: totalSeconds * 5)
    }

    func animateKeyPath(keyPath: String, duration: CFTimeInterval, times: [CFTimeInterval], values: [CGFloat]) {
        let animation = CAKeyframeAnimation(keyPath: keyPath)
        animation.keyTimes = times as [NSNumber]?
        animation.values = values
        animation.calculationMode = .linear
        animation.duration = duration
        animation.repeatCount = Float.infinity
        layer.add(animation, forKey: animation.keyPath)
    }

    func animateStrokeHueWithDuration(duration: CFTimeInterval) {
        let count = 36
        let animation = CAKeyframeAnimation(keyPath: "strokeColor")
        animation.keyTimes = (0 ... count).map { NSNumber(value: CFTimeInterval($0) / CFTimeInterval(count)) }
        animation.values = (0 ... count).map {
            UIColor(hue: CGFloat($0) / CGFloat(count), saturation: 1, brightness: 1, alpha: 1).cgColor
        }
        animation.duration = duration
        animation.calculationMode = .linear
        animation.repeatCount = Float.infinity
        layer.add(animation, forKey: animation.keyPath)
    }

}
```

Comment: Looks great! thank you! you have a guide for animations?

Comment: The [Core Animation Essentials video from WWDC 2011](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2011-421/) is very informative.

Comment: @robmayoff how did you create a gif of that indicator? I have code for this indicator, but I'm curious to how you translated it to a gif so well.

Comment: I ran the code in the simulator and used LICEcap to record it.

Comment: For **Swift 3**: layerClass is now imported as a computed class property in Swift. So for layer class you should use this:  `override class var layerClass: AnyClass {
        return CAShapeLayer.self
    }`

Comment: How can I add it in my view controller ?         `let spinner:SpinnerView = SpinnerView(frame: CGRect(x:0, y: 0, width: 120, height: 120));
self.view.addSubview(spinner);` and i can't see it :/

Comment: @robmayoff thanks for your awesome example, could you please show us how to call the spinner in another viewController ? because It seems I can't do it right.

Comment: great!! now How can I add a arrow in the front?

Comment: @MelanieJourne for example let screenSize: CGRect = UIScreen.main.bounds
        let myView = SpinnerView(frame: CGRect(x: screenSize.width/2, y: screenSize.height/2, width: 100, height: 100))
        self.view.addSubview(myView)

Comment: Hi, This is AWESOME. How can i set custom colors to the animation? thnx

Comment: There is an issue with this method: the animation disappear when you back home and reopen the app.

Comment: @greenpoisononeTV this is not the problem of the animation itself. UIKit stops ongoing animations if the app goes into inactive state. This could be fixed by observing application state and reactive animation if needed.

Comment: @sliwinski.lukas I see but I found a pod where the animation don't stop if the app is closed. May be the thought about this.

Comment: With swift 3.x this line: `rotations.append(start * 2 *.pi)` needs to be updated to `rotations.append(start * 2 * CGFloat.pi)`

Comment: Or just `rotations.append(start * 2 * .pi)`. I left out the space before `.pi` and Swift cares about such things.

Comment: @robmayoff if you could help me 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62623548/implement-css-into-swift-animation

Answer (score 3):

Try out my three custom Loader screen very simple :

Write below code in Viewcontoller.swift file

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

var signView = SignView(frame: CGRect.zero)
var testView = TestView(frame: CGRect.zero)
var testView1 = TestView1(frame: CGRect.zero)

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()        
    self.view.backgroundColor = UIColor.orange
}


override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(animated)
      addSignView()
    //addTestView()
    //addTestView1()
}

func addSignView() { 
    signView.frame = CGRect(x: 0,
                            y: 0,
                            width: UIScreen.main.bounds.size.width,
                            height: UIScreen.main.bounds.size.height)
    self.view.addSubview(signView)
    signView.addAnimationLayer()
}

func addTestView() {
    let boxSize: CGFloat = 200.0

    testView.frame = CGRect(x: 16,
                            y: 350,
                            width: boxSize,
                            height: boxSize)
    self.view.addSubview(testView)
    testView.addAnimationLayer()
}

func addTestView1() {

    testView1.frame = CGRect(x: 0,
                            y: 0,
                            width: UIScreen.main.bounds.size.width,
                            height: UIScreen.main.bounds.size.height)
    self.view.addSubview(testView1)
    testView1.addAnimationLayer()
}}
```

Now Add 3 Files inherit with UiView named > SignView , TestView and TestView1

Code for SignView.swift file

```
class SignView: UIView {


let upCircleLayer = CAShapeLayer.init()
var path = UIBezierPath.init()
var animationDuration : Double = 2
var frameHeight : CGFloat = 50.0

override init(frame: CGRect) {
    super.init(frame: frame)

    self.backgroundColor = UIColor.black.withAlphaComponent(0.5)
}

required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    super.init(coder: aDecoder)
}



var signWavePath : UIBezierPath {
    var clockCycle = true
    let yPoint = self.frame.size.height/2
    frameHeight =  self.frame.size.width/6
    for x in 1...24{

        if x%2 != 0 {

            let xpath =  UIBezierPath(arcCenter: CGPoint(x: CGFloat(x)*frameHeight/2, y: yPoint),
                         radius: frameHeight/2,
                         startAngle: 180.0 * .pi/180.0,
                         endAngle: 0.0,
                         clockwise: clockCycle)
            path.append(xpath)

            if(clockCycle){
                clockCycle = false
            }
            else{
                clockCycle = true
            }

        }
    }

    return path;
}

func addAnimationLayer() {


    // Add Upper Circle Layer
    upCircleLayer.fillColor = UIColor.clear.cgColor
    upCircleLayer.strokeColor = UIColor.white.cgColor
    upCircleLayer.lineWidth = 8.0
    upCircleLayer.path = signWavePath.cgPath
    layer.addSublayer(upCircleLayer)

    animateStrokeUpCircle()

    Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: animationDuration, target: self, selector: #selector(animateStrokeUpCircle), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
}


func animateStrokeUpCircle() {

    let strokeAnimation: CABasicAnimation = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "strokeEnd")
        strokeAnimation.fromValue = 0.0
        strokeAnimation.toValue = 1.0
        strokeAnimation.duration = animationDuration
        strokeAnimation.isRemovedOnCompletion = false
        upCircleLayer.add(strokeAnimation, forKey: nil)

        expand1()
}
func expand1() {

        let expandAnimation: CABasicAnimation = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "position")
        expandAnimation.fromValue = [0,sin(self.frame.width)]
        expandAnimation.toValue = [-self.frame.width,cos(self.frame.width)]
        expandAnimation.duration = animationDuration
        expandAnimation.fillMode = kCAFillModeForwards
        expandAnimation.isRemovedOnCompletion = false
        upCircleLayer.add(expandAnimation, forKey: nil)
}
```

}

Code for TestView File :

```
class TestView: UIView {

let upCircleLayer = CAShapeLayer.init()
let downCircleLayer = CAShapeLayer.init()

var path1 = UIBezierPath.init()
var path2 = UIBezierPath.init()

var animationDirection : Bool = true

override init(frame: CGRect) {
    super.init(frame: frame)
    self.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
}

required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    super.init(coder: aDecoder)
}



var up1Circle: UIBezierPath {
    return UIBezierPath(arcCenter: CGPoint(x: self.frame.size.width/4, y: self.frame.size.height/2),
                        radius: self.frame.size.height/4,
                        startAngle: 180.0 * .pi/180.0,
                        endAngle: 0.0,
                        clockwise: true)
}
var down2Circle: UIBezierPath {
    return UIBezierPath(arcCenter: CGPoint(x: 3*self.frame.size.width/4, y: self.frame.size.height/2),
                        radius: self.frame.size.height/4,
                        startAngle: 180.0 * .pi/180.0,
                        endAngle: 0.0,
                        clockwise: false)
}

var up22Circle: UIBezierPath {
    return UIBezierPath(arcCenter: CGPoint(x: 3*self.frame.size.width/4, y: self.frame.size.height/2),
                        radius: self.frame.size.height/4,
                        startAngle: 180.0 * .pi/180.0,
                        endAngle: 0.0,
                        clockwise: true)
}
var down11Circle: UIBezierPath {
    return UIBezierPath(arcCenter: CGPoint(x: self.frame.size.width/4, y: self.frame.size.height/2),
                        radius: self.frame.size.height/4,
                        startAngle: 180.0 * .pi/180.0,
                        endAngle: 0.0,
                        clockwise: false)
}



var up2Circle: UIBezierPath {
    return UIBezierPath(arcCenter: CGPoint(x: 3*self.frame.size.width/4, y: self.frame.size.height/2),
                        radius: self.frame.size.height/4,
                        startAngle: 0.0,
                        endAngle: 180.0 * .pi/180.0,
                        clockwise: true)
}
var down1Circle: UIBezierPath {
    return UIBezierPath(arcCenter: CGPoint(x: self.frame.size.width/4, y: self.frame.size.height/2),
                        radius: self.frame.size.height/4,
                        startAngle: 0.0,
                        endAngle: 180.0 * .pi/180.0,
                        clockwise: false)
}

func addAnimationLayer() {

    path1.append(up1Circle);
    path1.append(down2Circle);

    path2.append(down11Circle)
    path2.append(up22Circle)



    // Add Upper Circle Layer
    upCircleLayer.fillColor = UIColor.clear.cgColor
    upCircleLayer.strokeColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
    upCircleLayer.lineWidth = 8.0
    upCircleLayer.path = path1.cgPath
    layer.addSublayer(upCircleLayer)


     Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 2.0, target: self, selector: #selector(expand1), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)

}

func expand() {

    if animationDirection{
        //upCircleLayer.path = path1.cgPath
        let expandAnimation: CABasicAnimation = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "path")
        expandAnimation.fromValue = path1.cgPath
        expandAnimation.toValue = path2.cgPath
        expandAnimation.duration = 1.5
        //expandAnimation.fillMode = kCAFillModeForwards
        expandAnimation.isRemovedOnCompletion = false
        upCircleLayer.add(expandAnimation, forKey: nil)

        animationDirection = false
    }
    else{
        //upCircleLayer.path = path2.cgPath
        let expandAnimation: CABasicAnimation = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "path")
        expandAnimation.fromValue = path2.cgPath
        expandAnimation.toValue = path1.cgPath
        expandAnimation.duration = 1.5
        //expandAnimation.fillMode = kCAFillModeForwards
        expandAnimation.isRemovedOnCompletion = false
        upCircleLayer.add(expandAnimation, forKey: nil)
        animationDirection = true
    }


}


func expand1() {

    let expandAnimation: CABasicAnimation = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "position")
    expandAnimation.fromValue = [0,self.frame.height/2]
    expandAnimation.toValue = 500
    expandAnimation.duration = 2.0
    expandAnimation.fillMode = kCAFillModeForwards
    expandAnimation.isRemovedOnCompletion = false
    upCircleLayer.add(expandAnimation, forKey: nil)
}
```

}

And Code for TestView1.swift file

class TestView1: UIView {

```
let animationLayer = CAShapeLayer.init()

var path1 = UIBezierPath.init()
var path2 = UIBezierPath.init()
var path = UIBezierPath.init()
var circleRadius : CGFloat = 26.0;
var centerLineHeight : CGFloat = 40.0
var animationDuration : Double = 2.0

var animationDirection : Bool = true

override init(frame: CGRect) {
    super.init(frame: frame)
    self.backgroundColor = UIColor.black
}

required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    super.init(coder: aDecoder)
}


var centerMainLine: UIBezierPath {
    let frameSize = self.frame.size
    let centerLine = UIBezierPath()
    centerLine.move(to: CGPoint(x: frameSize.width/2, y: frameSize.height/2 - centerLineHeight/2))
    centerLine.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: frameSize.width/2, y: frameSize.height/2 + centerLineHeight/2))
    return centerLine
}

var upLeftCircle: UIBezierPath {
    let frameSize = self.frame.size
    let halfCircle = UIBezierPath(arcCenter: CGPoint(x: frameSize.width/2 - circleRadius, y: frameSize.height/2 - centerLineHeight/2),
                        radius: circleRadius,
                        startAngle: 180.0 * .pi/180.0,
                        endAngle: 0.0,
                        clockwise: true)
    return halfCircle
}
var upRightCircle: UIBezierPath {
    let frameSize = self.frame.size
    let halfCircle = UIBezierPath(arcCenter: CGPoint(x: frameSize.width/2 + circleRadius, y: frameSize.height/2 - centerLineHeight/2),
                                  radius: circleRadius,
                                  startAngle: 180.0 * .pi/180.0,
                                  endAngle: 0.0,
                                  clockwise: true)
    return halfCircle
}
var downLeftCircle: UIBezierPath {
    let frameSize = self.frame.size
    let halfCircle = UIBezierPath(arcCenter: CGPoint(x: frameSize.width/2 - circleRadius, y: frameSize.height/2 + centerLineHeight/2),
                                  radius: circleRadius,
                                  startAngle: 180.0 * .pi/180.0,
                                  endAngle: 0.0,
                                  clockwise: false)
    return halfCircle
}
var downRightCircle: UIBezierPath {
    let frameSize = self.frame.size
    let halfCircle = UIBezierPath(arcCenter: CGPoint(x: frameSize.width/2 + circleRadius, y: frameSize.height/2 + centerLineHeight/2),
                                  radius: circleRadius,
                                  startAngle: 180.0 * .pi/180.0,
                                  endAngle: 0.0,
                                  clockwise: false)
    return halfCircle
}

func drawUpCircle(centerPoint:CGPoint, radiusValue:CGFloat) -> UIBezierPath {

    let halfCircle = UIBezierPath(arcCenter: centerPoint,
                                  radius: radiusValue,
                                  startAngle: 180.0 * .pi/180.0,
                                  endAngle: 0.0,
                                  clockwise: true)
    return halfCircle
}
func drawDownCircle(centerPoint:CGPoint,radiusValue:CGFloat) -> UIBezierPath {

    let halfCircle = UIBezierPath(arcCenter: centerPoint,
                                  radius: radiusValue,
                                  startAngle: 180.0 * .pi/180.0,
                                  endAngle: 0.0,
                                  clockwise: false)
    return halfCircle
}
func drawLine(fromPoint:CGPoint,toPoint:CGPoint) -> UIBezierPath {

    let line = UIBezierPath()
    line.move(to: fromPoint)
    line.addLine(to: toPoint)
    return line
}


func addAnimationLayer() {

    createPathOne()
    createPathTwo()
    createPath()

    // set Animation Layer design
    animationLayer.fillColor = UIColor.clear.cgColor
    animationLayer.strokeColor = UIColor.white.cgColor
    animationLayer.lineWidth = 8.0
    animationLayer.path = path.cgPath
    layer.addSublayer(animationLayer)
    expand1()
    Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 10.0, target: self, selector: #selector(expand1), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
}
func expand1() {

    let expandAnimation: CABasicAnimation = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "position")
    expandAnimation.fromValue = [0,0]
    expandAnimation.toValue = [-2000,0]
    expandAnimation.duration = 10.0
    expandAnimation.fillMode = kCAFillModeForwards
    expandAnimation.isRemovedOnCompletion = false
    animationLayer.add(expandAnimation, forKey: nil)
}
func expand() {
    animationLayer.path = centerMainLine.cgPath
    if animationDirection{

        let expandAnimation: CABasicAnimation = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "path")
        expandAnimation.fromValue = path1.cgPath
        expandAnimation.toValue = path2.cgPath
        expandAnimation.duration = animationDuration
        expandAnimation.fillMode = kCAFillModeBackwards
        expandAnimation.isRemovedOnCompletion = false
        animationLayer.add(expandAnimation, forKey: nil)

        animationDirection = false
    }
    else{
        let expandAnimation: CABasicAnimation = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "path")
        expandAnimation.fromValue = path2.cgPath
        expandAnimation.toValue = path1.cgPath
        expandAnimation.duration = animationDuration
        expandAnimation.fillMode = kCAFillModeForwards
        expandAnimation.isRemovedOnCompletion = false
        animationLayer.add(expandAnimation, forKey: nil)

        animationDirection = true
    }
}

func createPathOne(){

    path1.append(upLeftCircle);
    path1.append(centerMainLine);
    path1.append(downRightCircle)

}
func createPathTwo(){
    path2.append(downLeftCircle);
    path2.append(centerMainLine);
    path2.append(upRightCircle)
}

func createPath()  {
    let frameSize = self.frame.size;

    let lineHeight1 : CGFloat = 30
    let lineHeight2 : CGFloat = 20

    let radius1 : CGFloat = 40.0
    let radius2 : CGFloat = 20.0

    var lastPoint : CGPoint = CGPoint(x:0.0,y:frameSize.height/2 - lineHeight1/2)
    for i in 1...10{

        let p1 = drawUpCircle(centerPoint: CGPoint(x: lastPoint.x + radius1, y: lastPoint.y  ), radiusValue: radius1)
        lastPoint = p1.currentPoint;

        let p2 = drawLine(fromPoint: lastPoint , toPoint: CGPoint(x:lastPoint.x, y: lastPoint.y+lineHeight1))
        lastPoint = p2.currentPoint;

        let p3 = drawDownCircle(centerPoint: CGPoint(x:lastPoint.x + radius1, y: lastPoint.y), radiusValue: radius1)
        lastPoint = p3.currentPoint;

        let p4 = drawLine(fromPoint: lastPoint, toPoint: CGPoint(x:lastPoint.x, y: lastPoint.y - lineHeight2))
        lastPoint = p4.currentPoint;

        let p5 = drawUpCircle(centerPoint: CGPoint(x:lastPoint.x + radius2, y: lastPoint.y), radiusValue: radius2)
        lastPoint = p5.currentPoint;

        let p6 = drawLine(fromPoint: lastPoint, toPoint: CGPoint(x:lastPoint.x, y: lastPoint.y + lineHeight2))
        lastPoint = p6.currentPoint;

        let p7 = drawDownCircle(centerPoint: CGPoint(x:lastPoint.x + radius2, y: lastPoint.y), radiusValue: radius2)
        lastPoint = p7.currentPoint

        let p8  = drawLine(fromPoint: lastPoint, toPoint: CGPoint(x:lastPoint.x, y: lastPoint.y - lineHeight1))
        lastPoint = p8.currentPoint;

        path.append(p1)
        path.append(p2)
        path.append(p3)
        path.append(p4)
        path.append(p5)
        path.append(p6)
        path.append(p7)
        path.append(p8)

    }



}
```

}

Now run the code to check the Animation Loader. Comment/Uncomment other 2 loader method in viewDidAppear method of viewcontroller.

Enjoy!!

Answer (score 2):

If someone is looking for Objective C version of @rob mayoff solution

in SpinnerView.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

IB_DESIGNABLE
@interface SpinnerView : UIView

@end
```

in SpinnerView.m

```
#import "SpinnerView.h"
#import "Pose.h"


@implementation SpinnerView


- (instancetype) initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame{
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    return self;
}

- (instancetype) initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder{
    self = [super initWithCoder:aDecoder];
    return self;
}

- (CAShapeLayer*) layer {
    return (CAShapeLayer*)super.layer;
}

- (CAShapeLayer*) getLayer{
    return (CAShapeLayer*)super.layer;
}

+ (Class)layerClass{
    return [CAShapeLayer class];
}


- (void) layoutSubviews{
    [super layoutSubviews];
    [self getLayer].fillColor = nil;
    [self getLayer].strokeColor = [UIColor blackColor].CGColor;
    [self getLayer].lineWidth = 3;
    [self setPath];
}

- (void) didMoveToWindow{
    [self animate];
}

- (void) setPath{
    UIBezierPath* bezierPath = ([UIBezierPath bezierPathWithOvalInRect:CGRectInset(self.bounds,  [self getLayer].lineWidth/2,  [self getLayer].lineWidth/2)]);
    [self getLayer].path = bezierPath.CGPath;
}


- (NSArray*) poses{
    NSMutableArray* poses = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    [poses addObject:[[Pose alloc] initWith:0.0 start:0.000 length:0.7]];
    [poses addObject:[[Pose alloc] initWith:0.6 start:0.500 length:0.5]];
    [poses addObject:[[Pose alloc] initWith:0.6 start:1.000 length:0.3]];
    [poses addObject:[[Pose alloc] initWith:0.6 start:1.500 length:0.1]];
    [poses addObject:[[Pose alloc] initWith:0.2 start:1.875 length:0.1]];
    [poses addObject:[[Pose alloc] initWith:0.2 start:2.250 length:0.3]];
    [poses addObject:[[Pose alloc] initWith:0.2 start:2.625 length:0.7]];
    [poses addObject:[[Pose alloc] initWith:0.2 start:3.000 length:0.5]];

    return poses;
}

- (void) animate{
    CFTimeInterval time = 0;
    NSMutableArray* times = [NSMutableArray new];;
    CGFloat start = 0;
    NSMutableArray* rotations = [NSMutableArray new];
    NSMutableArray* strokeEnds  = [NSMutableArray new];

    NSArray* posses = [self poses];
    double totalSeconds = [[posses valueForKeyPath:@"@sum.secondsSincePriorPose"] doubleValue];

    for(Pose* pose in posses){
        time += pose.secondsSincePriorPose;
        [times addObject:[NSNumber numberWithDouble:time/totalSeconds]];
        start = pose.start;
        [rotations addObject:[NSNumber numberWithDouble:start*2*M_PI]];
        [strokeEnds addObject:[NSNumber numberWithDouble:pose.length]];
    }

    [times addObject:[times lastObject]];
    [rotations addObject:[rotations firstObject]];
    [strokeEnds addObject:[strokeEnds firstObject]];

    [self animateKeyPath:@"strokeEnd" duration:totalSeconds times:times values:strokeEnds];
    [self animateKeyPath:@"transform.rotation" duration:totalSeconds times:times values:rotations];

    [self animateStrokeHueWithDuration:totalSeconds * 5];
}


- (void) animateKeyPath:(NSString*)keyPath duration:(CFTimeInterval)duration times:(NSArray*)times values:(NSArray*)values{
    CAKeyframeAnimation* animation = [CAKeyframeAnimation animationWithKeyPath:keyPath];
    animation.keyTimes = times;
    animation.values = values;
    animation.calculationMode = kCAAnimationLinear;
    animation.duration = duration;
    animation.repeatCount = FLT_MAX;
    [[self getLayer] addAnimation:animation forKey:animation.keyPath];
}


- (void) animateStrokeHueWithDuration:(CFTimeInterval)duration{

    CAKeyframeAnimation* animation = [CAKeyframeAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"strokeColor"];
    NSMutableArray *keyTimes = [NSMutableArray array];
    NSMutableArray *values = [NSMutableArray array];

    for (NSInteger i = 0; i < 36; i++) {
        [keyTimes addObject: [NSNumber numberWithDouble:(CFTimeInterval)i/(CFTimeInterval)36]];
        [values addObject:(id)[UIColor colorWithHue:(CGFloat)i/(CGFloat)36 saturation:1 brightness:1 alpha:1].CGColor];
    }

    animation.keyTimes = keyTimes;
    animation.values = values;
    animation.calculationMode = kCAAnimationLinear;
    animation.duration = duration;
    animation.repeatCount = FLT_MAX;
    [[self getLayer] addAnimation:animation forKey:animation.keyPath];

}


@end
```

Pose.h

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface Pose : NSObject

@property CFTimeInterval secondsSincePriorPose;
@property CGFloat start;
@property CGFloat length;

- (instancetype) initWith:(CFTimeInterval)timeInterval start:(CGFloat)start length:(CGFloat)length;

@end
```

Pose.m

```
#import "Pose.h"
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@implementation Pose 

- (instancetype) initWith:(CFTimeInterval)timeInterval start:(CGFloat)start length:(CGFloat)length{
    self = [super init];
    self.start = start;
    self.length = length;
    self.secondsSincePriorPose = timeInterval;
    return self;
}


@end
```

Comment: any example usage in which we can call and use this?