# CAShapeLayer circle strokeEnd not connecting to start

Tags: ios, swift, caanimation

I'm creating a circle similar to the Android material design loading indicator seen on the right [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NvceI.gif), but the circle isn't completing itself.

```swift
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    var baseLayer = CAShapeLayer()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        setUp()
    }

    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidAppear(animated)
        animate()
    }

    private func setUp() {
        view.layer.addSublayer(baseLayer)
        let basePath = UIBezierPath(arcCenter: view.center,
                                    radius: 100,
                                    startAngle: CGFloat.pi / 2,
                                    endAngle: 2 * CGFloat.pi,
                                    clockwise: true).cgPath
        baseLayer.strokeColor = UIColor.gray.cgColor
        baseLayer.path = basePath
        baseLayer.fillColor = UIColor.clear.cgColor
        baseLayer.lineWidth = 2
        baseLayer.position = view.center
        baseLayer.strokeEnd = 0
    }

    private func animate() {
        CATransaction.begin()
        let strokeEndAnimation = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "strokeEnd")
        strokeEndAnimation.toValue = 1
        strokeEndAnimation.fillMode = .forwards
        strokeEndAnimation.isRemovedOnCompletion = false
        strokeEndAnimation.timingFunction = CAMediaTimingFunction(name: .easeInEaseOut)

        let rotationAnimation = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "transform.rotation")
        rotationAnimation.toValue = CGFloat.pi
        rotationAnimation.fillMode = .forwards
        rotationAnimation.timingFunction = CAMediaTimingFunction(name: .easeInEaseOut)
        rotationAnimation.isRemovedOnCompletion = false

        let group = CAAnimationGroup()
        group.duration = 1.5
        group.repeatCount = 0
        group.fillMode = .forwards
        group.isRemovedOnCompletion = false
        group.animations = [strokeEndAnimation, rotationAnimation]

        baseLayer.add(group, forKey: "animations")
        CATransaction.commit()
    }
}
```

The image below shows what I'm talking about. It's correctly stopping at 3*pi/2 but I believe the strokeEnd is incorrectly stopping at pi. I tried various different configurations of strokeEnd and transform animations, but nothing seems to work. Modifying the strokeEnd `toValue` animation doesn't change anything.

[image: Gif of issue]

Comment: Have you looked at this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33453812/create-spinning-circle-loading-animation

Comment: @DonMag I saw that yeah. It's similar, but I want the circle to actually complete itself. The image I posted is the current completed state - I need it to actually connect. It's has a startAngle of Pi/2 then rotates to 3Pi/2, but the end of the line at Pi should be connecting at 3Pi/2. Does that make sense? https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uibezierpath/1624358-init

Comment: I'm a bit confused about what you want the end result to be here... you want a full circle to be drawn *and* for the whole thing to rotate as it is being drawn?

Comment: If you update your question with the full class (or at least enough so we can copy/paste and see it), we can take a look. Tough to help with only partial code.

Comment: @DavidSteppenbeck I attached a GIF of the issue. I need it to connect at the top of the circle at 12 o'clock (3Pi/2)

Comment: @DonMag I edited with a trimmed down version of the VC and attached a GIF of the issue

Comment: To troubleshoot: Have you tried removing the rotation animation from the group to ensure that the strokeEnd animation works as you've written it?

Comment: @Grady - try `endAngle: 3 * CGFloat.pi` (3 instead of 2)

Comment: @Grady - actually, make that `endAngle: 2.5 * CGFloat.pi`

Comment: @DonMag Ahhh that was it! Thank you so much. If you want to submit an answer I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PI is one-half of the circle. If you remove the rotation, and use this as your `basePath`:

```
    basePath = UIBezierPath(arcCenter: view.center,
                            radius: 100,
                            startAngle: 0,
                            endAngle: 1.0 * CGFloat.pi,
                            clockwise: true).cgPath
```

[image]

The line will start at 3:00 and go to 9:00

If you start at one-half PI:

```
    basePath = UIBezierPath(arcCenter: view.center,
                            radius: 100,
                            startAngle: CGFloat.pi / 2,
                            endAngle: 1.0 * CGFloat.pi,
                            clockwise: true).cgPath
```

[image]

Your line goes from 6:00 to 9:00

Add a half-PI to the endAngle:

```
    basePath = UIBezierPath(arcCenter: view.center,
                            radius: 100,
                            startAngle: CGFloat.pi / 2,
                            endAngle: 1.5 * CGFloat.pi,
                            clockwise: true).cgPath
```

[image]

and you get 6:00 to 12:00, which is *almost* what you want.

Now you add a rotation of PI (remember, that's one-half of a full circle):

[image]

and you're at 12:00 to 6:00.

To bring the end up to 12:00, gotta add another PI

```
    var basePath = UIBezierPath(arcCenter: view.center,
                                radius: 100,
                                startAngle: CGFloat.pi / 2,
                                endAngle: 2.5 * CGFloat.pi,
                                clockwise: true).cgPath
```

[image]