# Implement CSS into Swift Animation

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I have a loader written in CSS inside HTML.
And I want to achieve exact same thing in my iOS App.

Here is the CSS of the loader.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <style>
    @-webkit-keyframes spin {
        0% {
            -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
            -ms-transform: rotate(0deg);
            transform: rotate(0deg);
        }
        50% {
            -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);
            -ms-transform: rotate(360deg);
            transform: rotate(360deg);
        }
        100% {
            -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);
            -ms-transform: rotate(360deg);
            transform: rotate(360deg);
        }
    }
    @keyframes spin {
        0% {
            -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
            -ms-transform: rotate(0deg);
            transform: rotate(0deg);
        }
        100% {
            -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);
            -ms-transform: rotate(360deg);
            transform: rotate(360deg);
        }
    }
    .loader {
        display: block;
        width: 75px;
        height: 75px;
        margin: 0 auto;
        border-radius: 50%;
        border: 1px solid transparent;
        border-top-color: #ff9000;
        -webkit-animation: spin 2s linear infinite;
        animation: spin 2s linear infinite;
        position: fixed;
        z-index: 9999;
        left: 0;
        right: 0;
        top: 50%;
        transform: translateY(-50%)
    }
    .loader:before {
        content: "";
        position: absolute;
        top: 5px;
        left: 5px;
        right: 5px;
        bottom: 5px;
        border-radius: 50%;
        border: 1px solid transparent;
        border-top-color: #f00;
        -webkit-animation: spin 3s linear infinite;
        animation: spin 3s linear infinite
    }
    
    .loader:after {
        content: "";
        position: absolute;
        top: 11px;
        left: 11px;
        right: 11px;
        bottom: 11px;
        border-radius: 50%;
        border: 1px solid transparent;
        border-top-color: #0a00b2;
        -webkit-animation: spin 1.5s linear infinite;
        animation: spin 1.5s linear infinite
    }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="loader"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

If there is any library, tool or anything which can help me to get the exact same tool in my iOS app, it will be very helpful.

I tried to modify the same look but even after tweaking so much, I was unable to exact same result.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You could begin with breaking down _what_ is happening and then translating to SwiftUI. From what I can see (though having zero experience with css) you have 3 shapes (arcs) that rotate (with linear timing curve) indefinitely around the same center with 1.5, 2 and 3 second durations. So the question could become "How do I make and animate shapes in SwiftUI?"

Comment: @AlladinianI tried but I was unable to achieve the same experience that's posted here

Comment: You will get more help if you edit your question to include an animated GIF of the effect you want. You also need to include the Swift code you've written.

Comment: @robmayoff just click on "Run code snippet" button below above code
Also, I have added my code you can have a look at it, and if you have any suggestions for improvements then you’re most welcomed.

Comment: Revisiting this, I cannot for the love of me understand why I posted a `SwiftUI` implementation (and everyone being super nice to not call me out on this ). Anyway, glad you found a solution. I'm keeping the answer in case anyone is interested in a SUI approach.

Comment: @Alladinian I am pretty sure your SwiftUI implementation is great but I don't know much of SwiftUI also I was implementing this on production so using SwiftUI was not possible since the architecture of the app is kinda old.
Also, I searched for many solutions, modifying third party pods helped me, but the library itself was having issues with the application, so I decided to write my own method, sorry for posting it here this late was busy in things.
But this is working perfectly as intended.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess I have achieved what I initially wanted.

```
import UIKit

class CustomLoader: UIViewController {
    
    static let shared = CustomLoader()
    var arcsNotAdded: Bool = true
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.view.backgroundColor = .clear
    }
    
    func showLoader(_ interactionEnabled: Bool = true) {
        if let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate, let window = appDelegate.window, let rootViewController = window?.rootViewController {
            var topViewController = rootViewController
            let topVCArray = topViewController.children
            for obj in topVCArray where obj is CustomLoader { return }
            while topViewController.presentedViewController != nil {
                topViewController = topViewController.presentedViewController!
            }
            if topVCArray.count == 1 && topVCArray.first is InitialLandingController { //HOTFix for initial landing controller
                topViewController = topVCArray.first!
            }
            topViewController.addChild(self)
            topViewController.view.addSubview(view)
            didMove(toParent: topViewController)
            view.autoresizingMask = [.flexibleWidth, .flexibleHeight]
            view.frame = CGRect(topViewController.view.center.x, topViewController.view.center.y, 20, 20)
            view.center = topViewController.view.center
            kAppDelegate.window?.isUserInteractionEnabled = interactionEnabled
            arcsNotAdded ? configureArcs() : debugPrint("Arcs are already added")
        }
    }
    
    func hideLoader() {
        self.willMove(toParent: nil)
        self.view.removeFromSuperview()
        self.removeFromParent()
        kAppDelegate.window?.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
    }
    
    private func configureArcs() {
        arcsNotAdded = false
        
        let arcStartAngle: CGFloat = -CGFloat.pi / 2
        let arcEndAngle: CGFloat = 0
        let centrePoint = CGPoint(x: view.bounds.midX, y: view.bounds.midY)
        
        let outerCircle = CAShapeLayer()
        let middleCircle = CAShapeLayer()
        let innerCircle = CAShapeLayer()
        
        let circleColorOuter: CGColor = UIColor(red: 255/255, green: 144/255, blue: 0/255, alpha: 1.0).cgColor
        let circleColorMiddle: CGColor = UIColor(red: 255/255, green: 0/255, blue: 0/255, alpha: 1.0).cgColor
        let circleColorInner: CGColor = UIColor(red: 10/255, green: 0/255, blue: 178/255, alpha: 1.0).cgColor
                
        let outerPath = UIBezierPath(arcCenter: centrePoint, radius: CGFloat(77/2), startAngle: arcStartAngle, endAngle: arcEndAngle, clockwise: true)
        let midPath = UIBezierPath(arcCenter: centrePoint, radius: CGFloat(65/2), startAngle: arcStartAngle, endAngle: arcEndAngle, clockwise: true)
        let innerPath = UIBezierPath(arcCenter: centrePoint, radius: CGFloat(53/2), startAngle: arcStartAngle, endAngle: arcEndAngle, clockwise: true)

        configureArcLayer(outerCircle, forView: view, withPath: outerPath.cgPath, withBounds: view.bounds, withColor: circleColorOuter)
        configureArcLayer(middleCircle, forView: view, withPath: midPath.cgPath, withBounds: view.bounds, withColor: circleColorMiddle)
        configureArcLayer(innerCircle, forView: view, withPath: innerPath.cgPath, withBounds: view.bounds, withColor: circleColorInner)
        
        animateArcs(outerCircle, middleCircle, innerCircle)
    }
    
    private func configureArcLayer(_ layer: CAShapeLayer, forView view: UIView, withPath path: CGPath, withBounds bounds: CGRect, withColor color: CGColor) {
        layer.path = path
        layer.frame = bounds
        layer.lineWidth = 1.5
        layer.strokeColor = color
        layer.fillColor = UIColor.clear.cgColor
        layer.isOpaque = true
        view.layer.addSublayer(layer)
    }
    
    private func animateArcs(_ outerCircle: CAShapeLayer, _ middleCircle: CAShapeLayer, _ innerCircle: CAShapeLayer) {
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            let outerAnimation = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "transform.rotation")
            outerAnimation.toValue = 2 * CGFloat.pi
            outerAnimation.duration = 1.5
            outerAnimation.repeatCount = Float(UINT64_MAX)
            outerAnimation.isRemovedOnCompletion = false
            outerCircle.add(outerAnimation, forKey: "outerCircleRotation")
            
            let middleAnimation = outerAnimation.copy() as! CABasicAnimation
            middleAnimation.duration = 1
            middleCircle.add(middleAnimation, forKey: "middleCircleRotation")
            
            let innerAnimation = middleAnimation.copy() as! CABasicAnimation
            innerAnimation.duration = 0.75
            innerCircle.add(innerAnimation, forKey: "middleCircleRotation")
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Seems like a fun exercise, so here is a possible solution:

First, we need a way to make arcs. We can do that with `Shape` in SwiftUI:

```
struct Arc: Shape {
    let radius: CGFloat
    let angle: Double

    func path(in rect: CGRect) -> Path {
        Path { path in
            path.addArc(center: rect.center,
                        radius: radius,
                        startAngle: Angle(degrees: 0),
                        endAngle: Angle(degrees: angle),
                        clockwise: false)
        }
        .strokedPath(StrokeStyle(lineWidth: 1))
    }
}

extension CGRect {
    var center: CGPoint {
        .init(x: midX, y: midY)
    }
}
```

Note here that we have two inputs, `radius` & `angle` (in degrees). We also stroke the path with 1px line and define a convenient extension for getting the center of a rect.

Then we need something that will animate any view as an indefinite rotation for some duration:

```
private extension View {
    func rotationAnimation(duration: Double) -> Animation {
        Animation.linear(duration: duration / 2)
            .repeatForever(autoreverses: false)
    }

    func rotateFor(_ duration: Double, when isAnimating: Bool) -> some View {
        self.rotationEffect(Angle(degrees: isAnimating ? 360 : 0.0))
        .animation(isAnimating ? rotationAnimation(duration: duration) : .default)
    }
}
```

Note in the above snippet that I'm halving the duration to match the css (I noticed that there is a keyframe at 50% for a full spin)

Finally, let's put some shapes together in a `ZStack`:

```
struct LoadingView: View {
    @State var isAnimating: Bool = false
    
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            Arc(radius: 20, angle: 90)
                .rotateFor(1.5, when: isAnimating)
                .foregroundColor(.blue)
            Arc(radius: 25, angle: 90)
                .rotateFor(3.0, when: isAnimating)
                .foregroundColor(.red)
            Arc(radius: 30, angle: 90)
                .rotateFor(2.0, when: isAnimating)
                .foregroundColor(.orange)
        }
        .frame(width: 100, height: 100)
        .onAppear {
            self.isAnimating = true
        }
    }
}
```

which when previewed results to this:

```
struct LoadingView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        LoadingView()
    }
}
```

I guess you can play with the params to get it just right

[image]